# PHP error en la página de elección de método de pago

Tags: php, html

Tengo una aplicación en `php` de una tienda, me funciona todo excepto en la cuenta del admin, en la página de elección de métodos de pago, que me sale este error después de la lista de métodos:

> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\katana-master\admin\core\modules\index\view\payment_settings\widget-default.php on line 38

El código de esta página es este:

```
<?php
$settings=ConfigurationData::getAll();
$paymethods=PaymethodData::getAll();
?>
        <!-- Main Content -->
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
            <h1>Metodos de Pago</h1>
            <a href="./?view=settings" class="btn btn-default">General</a>
            <a href="./?view=payment_settings" class="btn btn-default">Metodos de Pago</a>
            </div>
            </div>
        <br>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
              <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                  <i class="fa fa-usd"></i> Metodos de Pago
                </div>
                    <table class="table table-bordered">
                      <tbody>
                      <?php foreach($paymethods as $pay):?>
                        <tr>
                        <td><?php echo $pay->name;?>
                        </td>
                        <td style="width:60px;">
                        <?php if($pay->is_active):?>
                          <a href="./?action=switchpm&id=<?php echo $pay->id; ?>" class="btn btn-xs btn-warning">Desactivar</a>
                        <?php else:?>
                          <a href="./?action=switchpm&id=<?php echo $pay->id; ?>" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary">Activar</a>
                        <?php endif;?>
                        </td>
                        </tr>
                      <?php endforeach;?>
                        </tbody>
                        </table>
                        </div>
<?php if(PaymethodData::getByName("paypal")->is_active):?>//AQUI DA EL ERROR
              <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                  <i class="fa fa-paypal"></i>Paypal
                </div>
<form method="post" action="./?action=updatepmsettings">
                    <table class="table table-bordered">
                      <tbody>
                        <?php
 if(count($settings)>0):?>
<?php foreach($settings as $cat):?>
  <?php 
  if(substr($cat->name, 0,7)=="paypal_"):?>
                        <tr>
                        <td><?php echo $cat->label; ?>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                        <input type="text" name="<?php echo $cat->name; ?>" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $cat->val;?>">
                        </td>
                        </tr>
 <?php endif; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
 <?php endif; ?>
                        <tr>
                        <td>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                        <input type="submit"  class="btn btn-success" value="Actualizar Datos PayPal">
                        </td>
                        </tr>
                      </tbody>
                    </table>
                    </form>
              </div>
            <?php endif; ?>
<?php if(PaymethodData::getByName("bank")->is_active):?>
              <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                  <i class="fa fa-bank"></i> Deposito Bancario
                </div>
<form method="post" action="./?action=updatepmsettings">
                    <table class="table table-bordered">
                      <tbody>
                      <?php
 if(count($settings)>0):?>
<?php foreach($settings as $cat):?>
  <?php 
  if(substr($cat->name, 0,5)=="bank_"):?>
                        <tr>
                        <td><?php echo $cat->label; ?>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                        <input type="text" name="<?php echo $cat->name; ?>" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $cat->val;?>">
                        </td>
                        </tr>
 <?php endif; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
 <?php endif; ?>
                        <tr>
                        <td>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                        <input type="submit"  class="btn btn-success" value="Actualizar Datos PayPal">
                        </td>
                        </tr>
                      </tbody>
                    </table>
                    </form>
              </div>
            <?php endif; ?>
            </div>
          </div>
```

EDITO: La clase PaymethodData es esta:

```
<?php
class PaymethodData{
    public static $tablename="paymethod";
    public function PaymethodData(){
        $this->title="";
        $this->content="";
        $this->image="";
        $this->user_id="";
        $this->is_public="0";
        $this->created_at="NOW()";
    }
    public function add(){
        $sql="insert into ".self::$tablename." (name,short_name,is_active)";
        $sql.="value (\"$this->name\",\"$this->short_name\",$this->is_active)";
        Executor::doit($sql);
    }
    public static function delById($id){
        $sql="delete from ".self::$tablename." where id=$id";
        Executor::doit($sql);
    }
    public function del(){
        $sql="delete from ".self::$tablename." where id=$this->id";
        Executor::doit($sql);
    }
//Partiendo de que ya tenemos creado un objecto PaymethodData previamente utilizamos el contexto
    public function update(){
        $sql="update ".self::$tablename." set name=\"$this->name\",short_name=\"$this->short_name\",is_active=\"$this->is_active\" where id=$this->id";
        Executor::doit($sql);
    }
    public function update_active(){
        $sql="update ".self::$tablename." set is_active=\"$this->is_active\" where id=$this->id";
        Executor::doit($sql);
    }
    public static function getById($id){
        $sql="select * from ".self::$tablename." where id=$id";
        $query=Executor::doit($sql);
        return Model::one($query[0],new PaymethodData());
    }
    public static function getByName($name){
        $sql="select * from ".self::$tablename." where short_name=\"$name\"";
        $query=Executor::doit($sql);
        return Model::one($query[0],new PaymethodData());
    }
    public static function getByPreffix($id){
        $sql="select * from ".self::$tablename." where short_name=\"$id\"";
        $query=Executor::doit($sql);
        return Model::one($query[0],new PaymethodData());
    }
    public static function getAll(){
        $sql="select * from ".self::$tablename;
        $query=Executor::doit($sql);
        return Model::many($query[0],new PaymethodData());
    }
    public static function getActives(){
        $sql="select * from ".self::$tablename." where is_active=1";
        $query=Executor::doit($sql);
        return Model::many($query[0],new PaymethodData());
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: El error te esta diciendo que `PaymethodData::getByName("paypal")` no devuelve un objeto y por tal motivo no puedes acceder a `->is_active`. Para obtener una respuesta es necesario que edites tu pregunta y agregues el código de la clase `PaymethodData`

Comment: Marcos ya he editado la pregunta con la clase que me comentas.

Comment: ¿Podrías editar tu pregunta y agregar lo que hace le método `Model::one()` y las partes/métodos relacionadas al mismo? Se me ocurre que cuando `$query[0]` no existe, no debe devolver la instancia que creas (_segundo parámetro)_. Por otro lado, _como no se que hace dicho método_, pero puedo ver que construyes un `new PaymethodData()`, ¿has tenido en cuenta que 'is_active' no es una propiedad en dicha clase? ¿No será que necesitas usar `is_public`?

Comment: Sinceramente, no he creado yo el código, sino que lo he cogido de internet. Vi que estaba bien el diseño y, para aprender un poco, lo descargué y al probarlo me ha dado ese error.

Comment: He buscado por internet y poniendo este if delante de ese if, no se si lo he arreglado o no, pero por lo menos ya no da ese error y aparece el boton del formulario que se crea debajo para meter los datos de ese tipo de pago: `if(is_null($paymethods))`